# просить/попросить and спрашивать/спросить - what is difference(s) between these verbs?

Tags: перевод, значения, глаголы

Unfortunately i will keep asking these kind of questions here on stackexchange. Please tell me which verb group on question title the verb ***to ask***  in English? And why translator gives same result which is the verb ***to ask*** in English for both of them? Please explain with some examples in two languages English and Russian. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are asking **something** (and expect something to be said in response), you use *спросить*:

> Спроси его, как пройти в библиотеку // Ask him which way the library is.

If you are asking **for something** (and expect something is done or given to you), you use *попросить*:

> Попроси его открыть тебе дверь // Ask him to open the door for you.
>
> Попроси у него машину // Ask him for his car.

Answer (score 6):

**Спросить** - means that you expect ONLY verbal answer.
Спроси его который час? (Ask him what time is it now?)

**Попросить** - means that you expect someone to do some action for you or you want to get a "physical" thing from someone.
Попроси его позвонить Кэт. (Ask him to call Kat)
Попроси у него ручку. (Ask him a pen)

Answer (score 0):

просить - is an action, it is adressed to some person to get something from, or do something to you, or somebody; it's similar to 'beg', beggin' a pardon
спросить - is about making any question, this is actually a verb 'to ask', when you trying to get some information you do this: спрашиваешь.